# what does `_TYPE_fpos_t;` mean?

Tags: c, linux, vxworks

vxTypes.h

```
#if !defined(__RTP__)
#ifdef _TYPE_fpos_t
#define _FPOS_T
_TYPE_fpos_t;
#undef _TYPE_fpos_t
#endif
#endif /* __RTP__ */
```

UPDATE 00:

stdio.h

```
typedef struct fpos_t
    {   /* file position */
    long _Off;  /* can be system dependent */
    _Mbstatet _Wstate;
    } fpos_t
```

and i have a compiling error (conflict) in `fpos_t` type

```
error: conflicting declaration 'struct fpos_t'...'fpos_t' has a previous declaration as `typedef long int fpos_t'
```

so i need to understand the code first to fix it, can someone explain what does the code do, specially the `_TYPE_fpos_t;` part?

Comment: Well, that depends on what `_TYPE_fpos_t` expands to. You could try checking with `gcc -E`.

Comment: @DanielFischer may you please check update 00 that could give you better idea about the problem

Comment: Looks like `_TYPE_fpos_t` might expand to `typedef long fpos_t`. But to check it, go looking for its definition, either in `vxTypes.h` or in some header (recursively) included in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Assuming you're using the gcc toolset, use "-nostdinc" compiler option to prevent GCC from using the default search path. (The diab toolset should have a similar option.) Your project makefile should already contain a list of "-I*dir*" entries that should make system headers visible to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If the macro `_TYPE_fpos_t` is defined :

- define the macro `_FPOS_T`;
- call the macro `_TYPE_fpos_t`;
- undefine the macro `_TYPE_fpos_t`.

Anyway, it depends on the rest of the code (definition of `_TYPE_fpos_t`, among other).

Answer (score 0):

If `__RTP__` is not defined and `_TYPE_fpos_t` is defined, define `_FPOS_T`, call the macro`_TYPE_fpos_t` and undefine `_TYPE_fpos_t` afterwards.

Comment: "define _FPOS_T as _TYPE_fpos_t" -> I don't see any `\\`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you please explain line #4 in vxTypes.h `_TYPE_fpos_t;` ?

Comment: Thanks mates, totally overseen this ^^

Answer (score 0):

It (`_TYPE_fpos_t`) is a name reserved for the implementation to use as it wishes.  You interfere with it at your peril.

In this case, it is probably used to control the `typedef` for the type `fpos_t`, which may be defined in multiple headers, but should only be defined once (under C99 or earlier rules) regardless of how many of the headers are included and the order in which they're included.  It's possible there's a similar mechanism around other types and macros that are defined in multiple headers (`NULL`, `size_t` being two primary examples).

Learning how to write headers from looking at system headers is hard work.  The pressures and constraints on a system header are phenomenal, and lead to all sorts of contortions.